# Style properties not working in IE using AngularJs and HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div style="color:{{color}}">Testing</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.color = "#996600";
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Color properties not working in IE, but chrome and firefox are working

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the updated code:

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-style="{color:color}">Testing</div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.color = "#996600";
    });
</script>
```

As you are using angularJs you need to define ng-style

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using expression using `{{}}`, use `ng-style` directive.

```
<div ng-style="{color: color}">Testing</div>
```

Angular has issues when using `style`. [Refer](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `ng-style` directive:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

`style` is HTML attribute where as `ng-style` in Angular Attribute.
So that Please use below notation

`<div ng-style="{color:color}">Testing</div>`

if want angular Notification

```
<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-style="color:{{color}}">Testing</div>
   </div>
</body>
```